# Hide tabs (fragments) on swipe view?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am finally catching up with the Android 4.0+ world and switching my activities to fragments. I am implementing the swipe view style tabs and need to be able to disable tabs based on an extra I am passing into the activity. My old way of doing this was this, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this with swipe views.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The tabHost no longer applies.  Now I have a FragmentPagerAdapter and ViewPager, but no clue how to use them to disable the tab.  Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to determine how to do this, however I don't know that it is the best way. What I had to do was pass a boolean value into my implementation of the FragmentPagerAdapter and only allow create the one fragment if I am in search mode.

```
    /**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    boolean isSearching = false;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, boolean isSearching) {
        super(fm);
        this.isSearching = isSearching; 
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            fragment = new UserGeneralFragment();
            break;

        case 1:
            if (!isSearching) fragment = new CommentListFragment();
            break;
        }

        return fragment;            
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (!isSearching) return 2;
        else return 1;
    }   

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.activity_user_tab_general).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            if (!isSearching) return getString(R.string.activity_user_tab_comments).toUpperCase(l);
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```